# SelectInputText ValueChangeListener Issues in IceFaces 1.8

Tags: java, jsf, user-interface, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I am using ICEFaces 1.8 for my application. I have a few SelectInputText in a grid like this:

```
<ice:panelGrid columns="4">             
            <ice:selectInputText id="txtId"                             
                         valueChangeListener="#{employeeBean.searchIdListener}" partialSubmit="true"></ice:selectInputText>
            <ice:selectInputText id="txtFirstName"
                         valueChangeListener="#{employeeBean.searchFirstNameListener}" partialSubmit="true"></ice:selectInputText>
            <ice:selectInputText id="txtLastName"
                         valueChangeListener="#{employeeBean.searchLastNameListener}" partialSubmit="true"></ice:selectInputText>
            <ice:selectInputText id="txtPhoneNumber"
                         valueChangeListener="#{employeeBean.searchPhnNbrListener}" partialSubmit="true"></ice:selectInputText>
        </ice:panelGrid>
```

When I change the value of any one of the above SelectInputText, I can see that all the above four ValueChangeListener methods are getting executed - WHY?

Should not it be only the method getting executed whose SelectInputText have some value changes?

Please let me know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this stems from a misunderstanding of what the `partialSubmit` attribute is intended to do as well as a misunderstanding of the `valueChangeListener`.

When submitting a form by clicking a submit button lets say, all components in the form bound to a managed property value or assigned a managed bean method in `valueChangeListener` have their request values being submitted, processed and validated by the server.  Assuming that the validation phase is successful, those submitted values are passed to the `UPDATE_MODEL` phase where each valueChangeListener method will be called.

Basically, this method is **NOT** viewed as an Application Event like a Click or Change event.

Using an Ajax submit however we can control what components in the JSF form will be submitted, and which controls will be re-rendered to display their new values after the response has been received at the client.  The attribute `partialSubmit` however simply works in conjunction with an Ajax request to minimize the size of the ViewState and the request for performance reasons.  Functionally this `partialSubmit` attribute alone does not have any real effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The panel grid posted above is present in a form. When the first time the page loads, all the four value change listeners are invoked. But seconf times onward, only the ValueChangeListener specific to a single component is invoked. Any specific reasons for this? Why not the second time also, all the methods are invoked?

Comment: Also, for a selectInputText, if I remove the partialSubmit then also the ValueChange listener method is getting triggered...why?

Comment: @user182944 Your question says that all valueChangeListeners are being invoked and thats bad, now you are saying only one is invoked when you want all of them invoked.  What is your problem then because you are doing a terrible job of explaining your misunderstanding.  I cannot tell anymore of your situation unless you were to edit your question to provide all of your code.

Comment: My bad only :( The code contains only a form and 4 selectInputText with both valueChangeListener and partial submit set to true. All the listener methods are getting invoked for the very first time. Next time onwards, only the specific ones are invoked. This is what I tried to say. Do you know why it behaves like that?  Anyways, your answer was very helpful for my concept.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably happening because `<ice:selectInputText>` intial values are **NULL** and first partial or full submit will result in **EMPTY string** being submitted from the page.

Intialize your selectInputText with empty Strings to avoid this or you can add below in JSF 2.x,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
         javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL
    </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Also to add to the Icefaces , Its partial submit is bit confusing  . *It is more like a Full Ajax Submit with partial Ajax/DOM rendering. There are several cases where icefaces 1.8 will execute multiple components on the page , however it avoids it in datatable column,panelSeries etc.*